# how to give desired name to reducer output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i am using hadoop 0.20.2 version , i just want to give a custom name for the reducer's output based on partition key.can any one suggest on this?

thanks

```
 public static class CustomPartioner extends Partitioner<Text, PairWritable>{

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, PairWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s = value.getone();

        if (numReduceTasks ==0){
            return 0;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("wood")){

            return 0;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Masonry")){
            return 1%numReduceTasks;
        }

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Reinforced Concrete")){
            return 2%numReduceTasks;
        }
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Reinforced Masonry")){
            return 3%numReduceTasks;
        }

        else
            return 4%numReduceTasks;

    }   

}
```

Comment: Give a custom name to what?  You want this name as a parameter to the reducer?

Comment: not as a parameter to the reducer. i just want to change the reducer partitoner name i.e. part-r-00000 to wood-r-00000 , Masonry-r-00000 some thing like this..

Comment: is any one know how to change reducer file name?

Comment: Try using [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)

Comment: i am using hadoop version 0.20.2.it is not having multiple outputs.